# Is there a OnExit or Leave event on ASP.NET textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to run some code on server when user leaves the Textbox, it will do some calculations on what has been typed. I'd rather avoid doing it with jQuery, because it would involve creating a JSON server, etc.

Isn't there a way to do a postback for such an event?

Comment: i wouldn't give up on jQuery.  You can use jQuery to do all aspects of the clientside code for this without needing to parse a lick of JSON at the server.

Comment: The thing is that the processing must access some data from DB.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET then you've already got a server application that can return JSON.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The TextBox has an [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) property to cause a postback when the user leaves the client-side textbox. There you can use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event to call some serverside code.

Comment: But I do not want to make a call to the server on every change made on the text. Only when the user finishes typing and leaves the field is that the data is ready to be processed...

Comment: @Adrian - the AutoPostBack only fires when the user leaves the textbox. Only *then* can the server react to the TextChanged event. So it works as required.

Comment: You're right. The name of the event is misleading. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

What about the `Textchanged Event` of the Textbox? It is fired when we input/change some text and then leave the textbox.

Comment: I would note (as mentioned by Hans Kesting above) the `TextChanged` event is only fired immediately after leaving the TextBox if `AutoPostback` is set to "True".

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPara" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnTextChanged="txtPara_TextChanged" onblur ="myFunction()"></asp:TextBox>

  <script>
        function myFunction() {

            __doPostBack("<%=txtPara%>", **txtPara_TextChanged**);

        }</script>
```