# How to get all events on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, events, webforms

I am trying to create a simple WebForm in Visual Studio 2017. I have a textbox and I have to catch "Leave" event on it, but these are the only events available:

[image: Events]

I've been searching for similar questions and problems but I did not find any solutions.

Comment: Something that just is not there cannot be found, for more see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750580/is-there-a-onexit-or-leave-event-on-asp-net-textbox and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526429/how-to-get-gotfocus-lostfocus-event-of-a-textbox-in-webforms-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Leave` event because ASP.NET runs on Server while the user's "leave" happens on the client. You could handle the `blur` event in JavaScript and then do a post back. Very nice solution is in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3866270/732221).

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior, you're working with a [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx).

It doesn't have a Leave event since it's a Web UI control. If you want a Leave event, you'll have to use Javascript (note that this will be Client-Side).